# Mouse coordination just work in short specific range javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javafx.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label mouseCoordination = new Label("?,?");
        mouseCoordination.setOnMouseMoved(e ->
                mouseCoordination.setText(e.getX()+","+ e.getY())
        );
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPrefHeight(100);
        root.setPrefWidth(400);
        root.getChildren().add(mouseCoordination);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Here i tried to get mouse coordination, So i wrote this but it just work in short range like (0,0) to (48,17) and it doesn't update label after that. i actually wrote that in base of a question in site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the label isn't `width` × `height` and you added the mouse listener to the label; if you add the listener to `root`, it will work the way you wanted.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Label mouseCoordination = new Label("?,?");

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.setPrefWidth(400);
    root.setPrefHeight(100);
    root.getChildren().add(mouseCoordination);
    root.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        mouseCoordination.setText(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Just to be clear, you added the mouse listener to the label which only has a width of 30 and a height of 40, for example; the size depends on the text being displayed and how much space it takes up. The mouse listener is only called if your mouse is on the label; however, since you wanted it to show your current mouse position, it wouldn't work unless the label had the same width and height as the window.

Comment: English words please..

Comment: what? the answer is in english??

Comment: _u_ or _ur_ are not words ;) Please edit and replace with complete words

Comment: Yes they're abbreviations but i don't see a problem.
Changed it tho.

Comment: thanks - you missed one in the first line, though :)

Comment: @Suic: The problem is for the reader—both human and assistive. Thank you for your attention to such details. Please don't hesitate to edit my changes to reflect your intent.